# MySQL - Large database, improve search time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, indexing

I have two rather big tables (`threads` and `posts`) that include a ton of forum posts. I really have to improve my search time. Even doing a normal search where `COLUMN = VALUE` will take 15 seconds. Doing a `LIKE` often crash the entire website (timeout).

Here's a picture of my site and two tables:
[image]

The `threads` table contains about 430,000 rows.

The `posts` table contains about 2,700,000 rows.

And I need to combine these in a query to get the results I want.

Don't bother about the search boxes on the website for now. Let's just start off with this query right here and start improving this one first.

```
SELECT p.id, t.id, t.title, t.threadstarter, t.replies, t.views, t.board, p.dateposted FROM threads t
JOIN posts p
ON t.id = p.threadid
WHERE t.title = 'sell'
GROUP BY t.id
```

This query will take about 15 seconds to get all threads and posts where the thread title is "sell". How would I improve this, making it just a second or two? Is this even possible with MySQL in two tables with these sizes?

And from there on, I would have to make a `LIKE` (unless there is another method). Because the users on the website will most likely not search for an exact match. And I'd want to include any title that includes the world "sell". So that would be like this:

```
SELECT p.id, t.id, t.title, t.threadstarter, t.replies, t.views, t.board, p.dateposted FROM threads t
JOIN posts p
ON t.id = p.threadid
WHERE t.title LIKE '%sell%'
GROUP BY t.id
```

Which I am not even going to bother measuring. It's crashing the website (too long time to execute). So this one really(!) needs improvement.

How should I even approach this? Should I even use MySQL? What options do I have? I do not want a user to sit and wait 30-300 seconds for a query to finish. At most 5 seconds.

Is this possible, with such large tables?
I've heard using "MATCH" and "AGAINST" could be better than a "COLUMN" LIKE "VALUE". But then I need to make all the columns freetext. Any downsides of doing that?

If there's anyone out there that's worked with a ~3 million row MySQL database, then please let me know how you handled it (if you did).

Comment: You are aggregating by the thread id but using `select *`.  That fetches the posts as well, or rather arbitrary columns from matching posts.  The query doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I want to gather all the post data that belong to a thread, then I need to do a join on these two. This will give me all the post data to the original post in the forum thread. If I remove the `GROUP BY t.id` then it will also include all other posts from those threads.

Comment: I updated my query now in the first post, to show exactly which values I want from each table. Just to clarify it a bit.

Comment: . . No.  It will give you columns from arbitrary matching rows.  Nothing in your query specifies that the rows come from the first post.

Comment: Well, I am getting the output I need. But, I just need to improve the query speed. Any input on that? What options do I have, other than a LIKE?

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `INDEX`. Just try to create an index on one of the table which has more records or the master though its an inner join still itll make it easier to inner join the two.

Plus, I simply din understand usage of `group by` without any aggregation as its `select *..` in the query.

```
    CREATE  INDEX Index_NAME ON 
       threads(title);
```

Comment: If I want to gather all the post data that belong to a thread, then I need to do a join on these two. This will give me all the post data to the original post in the forum thread. If I remove the GROUP BY t.id then it will also include all other posts from those threads.

Comment: I guess that join condition does that needful

Comment: I updated my query now in the first post, to show exactly which values I want from each table. Just to clarify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to express your first query is:

```
SELECT p.id, t.id, t.title, t.threadstarter, t.replies, t.views, t.board, p.dateposted
FROM threads t JOIN
     posts p
     ON t.id = p.threadid
WHERE t.title = 'sell' AND
      p.dateposted = (SELECT MIN(p2.dateposted) FROM posts p2 WHERE p2.threadid = p.threadid);
```

This gets rid of the `GROUP BY`, so it might improve performance.  In particular, you want indexes on:

- `threads(title, id)`
- `posts(threadid, dateposted)`

Comment: So when I create the indexes, I should do it like this?
`CREATE INDEX Index_name ON threads(title, id), posts(threadid, dateposted)` ? But should I then use the index somehow in my query? Or what does this really do to improve the speed? I just create index and that's it? What is the index name for?


    .... Edit: the query did not even execute. It was loading for minutes in the background. No error, no  nothing

Comment: The indexes need to be created in two separate statements, one for each index.

Answer (score 0):

give these two articles a read.

[how to optimize mysql queries for speed and performance](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-optimize-mysql-queries-for-speed-and-perfor)

[MySQL Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` with a leading wild card must scan all 430,000 rows:

```
WHERE t.title LIKE '%sell%'
```

Change to this:

```
WHERE MATCH(t.title) AGAINST('+sell' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and have

```
FULLTEXT(title)
```

With that setup, the query can go directly to the few rows that have the 'word' `sell` in it.

Caveat:  There are restrictions on what `FULLTEXT` can search for -- only "words', not "stop words", only words of a certain minimum length, etc.